# Why does my character mesh deform when I animate the camera?

Tags: animation, mesh, camera

I've run into a problem. So I've got a character that I intend to use in an FPS, I've already done the animations for the mesh (like walking and jumping), and I tried to animate the camera to add some realism to the animations. But whenever I add a keyframe to the camera's position and rotation, and move the timeline slider my mesh gets deformed.
[image: screenshot 2]

This is what happens when I move the slider. The keyframe for the camera is on the first frame. The deformation is quite severe, and I still don't know how to fix it.

This is how it should look like:
[image: working example]

I've tried joining the mesh and the camera, parenting them, giving a bone to the camera, and adding a keyframe for all the options when you press <kbd>I</kbd>, but all these solutions don't work.

I would really appreciate a solution that can help me animate the camera on top of the animations that I already have without deforming the mesh as to not make matters more complicated.

Thank You!

This is the blend file

[image]

Comment: We need more detail to be able to help you.  Can you add your blend file to your question? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from your blend file to your question. I've keyframed the location and rotation, moved and rotated it, played the animation, and scrubbed the timeline. But I cannot see any deformations. Blender 2.93. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem, I haven't been rotating when I insert a keyframe.
Thank you @Blunder, your comment helped me alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is what happens when I move the slider. The keyframe for the camera is on the first frame.]

The screen-shot is above. The deformation is quite severe, and I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi. BSE is not like a common forum where you do follow-up posts. Instead, you should edit your question and add this info. Just done it for you, but next time it's up to you ;-)